# How to customize the TLS handshake process in Openssl?

Tags: authentication, ssl, openssl

I am learning TLS mutual authentication using Openssl.

During the TLS handshake process, I want to run the code I wrote separately for the two processes below.

1. Part of signing with your private key
2. Verification part of the certificate received from the other party

Note that I try to do this in a trustzone or a separate secure area.

I'm looking at the openssl content, and I'm not sure which APIs can handle these things.
I do not know how to approach this now.

If anyone knows about this, please reply.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - but maybe you are looking for some API which does not exist. OpenSSL does not provide you with an API for fine grained control of the handshake like signing. It will provide you with a callback for verification though, see [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a requirement for using TPM for Private Key. You should take a look at https://github.com/ThomasHabets/openssl-tpm-engine. This could be of some help. Apart from that, there is no known callbacks for Private Key Signing. But, as [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) correctly mentions, the [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) function can help you to add your own logic for validating the certificate received from Peer.